# How can I include HTML in the date format on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I would like Wordpress to render the post date as follows:

```
<small>Feb <b>29</b> 2012</small>;
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by escaping the HTML you want to include in the output in the date string, like so:

```
<small><?php the_time('M \<\b\>n\<\/\b\> Y') ?></small>
```

Comment: From the default theme "twentyten", this seems to be embeded on the twentyten_posted_on function. How would I go about entering this?

Comment: You can adjust the `twentyten_posted_on` function in `functions.php` to `echo` the content above. There's an outline of such an adjustment at: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-posted-date-and-by

Comment: Thanks rjz! I edit the get_the_date function to get_the_date('M \<\b\>n\<\/\b\> Y')

Answer (score 1):

Go to Stetting > General select date format you wanted..
I think first one match your needs

Answer (score 0):

Go here, it explain all: [[Codex] WordPress - Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

Comment: This is only for formatting the date. I want to inject html in the day.

Comment: Let me a sec, a try something

Comment: What is the theme you want to modify?